# Windows 7 Freezing and crashing

Tags: windows-7, freeze, crash, bsod

Ok. So when windows 10 came out I upgraded. I started getting problems left and right, then about 2 months ago I started getting freeze crashes and BSOD. So with errors coming out of my ears I got myself a new hard drive (so I could keep 10 for when all the bugs are worked out) and put 7 on it, now this hard drive had the same speck just twice the size.

However I am still getting BSOD:s however now only when playing a game...any game, though. It will also freeze without warning and the hard drive seems sluggish.

Now I don't know if the hard drive is faulty, one of the drivers is faulty, the OS is faulty, or if somethings is incompatible or a combination of problems.

Any advice or suggestions would be fantastic or if you can help fix the problem that would be life saving.

[My System's Dxdiag](http://freetexthost.com/rc0ul3ecuf)

First Two BSOD Crashes:

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was:
>   0x0000007e (0xffffffffc0000005, 0xfffff80002ef2d72,
>   0xfffff880033e06d8, 0xfffff880033dff30). A dump was saved in:
>   C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 110515-18283-01.

The third BSOD Crash:

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was:
>   0x0000003b (0x00000000c0000005, 0xfffff80002ef9d72,
>   0xfffff880098a0ce0, 0x0000000000000000). A dump was saved in:
>   C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id:110615-14274-01.

Thank you everyone for helping with this.

Comment: What are the full BSOD error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: Have you checked your dust level?  For older computers, most recurring crashes are caused by overheating.  Games use more processing power which generates more heat, which leads to more crashes due to overheating.  Check all the fans and heat sinks and vacuum out everything.  Sometimes this may require some disassembly.

Comment: [BSOD logs](http://freetexthost.com/1ojwyazmz3). -:- 

It is not a dust issue as its clean. also heating wise it's liquld cooled and the motherboard had notifide me in the past when I had a heating issuse. and the system is less than a year old

Comment: we need the actual dmp files and not this useless Bluescreenview text, so share the folder C:\Windows\Minidump

Comment: [110515-18283-01.dmp](http://www.industrialdimensions.co.uk/110515-18283-01.dmp), [110515-35459-01.dmp](http://www.industrialdimensions.co.uk/110515-35459-01.dmp), [110615-14274-01.dmp](http://www.industrialdimensions.co.uk/110615-14274-01.dmp)

Comment: ok, I posted an answer about what I saw from the dumps.

Answer (score 0):

Operating system intermittently crashes with a "0x0000007E" Stop error message on a computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2, hotfix available to download at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2528614

Stop error code 0x0000003B (SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION) on a computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 when you use some IEEE 1394 devices, hotfix is available to download at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/980932

Comment: the hot fix for 0x0000003B (SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION) gives me this: The Update is not applicable to your computer

Comment: Please try this KB2836373, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2836373  "0x0000003B" Stop error in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: I will do as soon as the hot fix system is back up

Comment: Ok that installed fine

Answer (score 0):

ok, I checked the dumps and 2 show this:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M (1000007e)
This is a very common bugcheck.  Usually the exception address pinpoints
the driver/function that caused the problem.  Always note this address
as well as the link date of the driver/image that contains this address.
Some common problems are exception code 0x80000003.  This means a hard
coded breakpoint or assertion was hit, but this system was booted
/NODEBUG.  This is not supposed to happen as developers should never have
hardcoded breakpoints in retail code, but ...
If this happens, make sure a debugger gets connected, and the
system is booted /DEBUG.  This will let us see why this breakpoint is
happening.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffffffc0000005, The exception code that was not handled
Arg2: fffff80002ef2d72, The address that the exception occurred at
Arg3: fffff880033e06d8, Exception Record Address
Arg4: fffff880033dff30, Context Record Address

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  7601.19018.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.150928-1507

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_SKU:  SKU

SYSTEM_VERSION:  To be filled by O.E.M.

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  2501

BIOS_DATE:  04/03/2014

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  M5A99X EVO R2.0

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Rev 1.xx

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: ffffffffc0000005

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff80002ef2d72

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff880033e06d8

BUGCHECK_P4: fffff880033dff30

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!KxWaitForLockOwnerShip+12
fffff800`02ef2d72 48890a          mov     qword ptr [rdx],rcx

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  fffff880033e06d8 -- (.exr 0xfffff880033e06d8)
ExceptionAddress: fffff80002ef2d72 (nt!KxWaitForLockOwnerShip+0x0000000000000012)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: ffffffffffffffff
Attempt to read from address ffffffffffffffff

CPU_MHZ: 10ee

CPU_VENDOR:  AuthenticAMD

CPU_FAMILY: 15

CPU_MODEL: 2

CPU_STEPPING: 0

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000005

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!KxWaitForLockOwnerShip+12
fffff800`02ef2d72 48890a          mov     qword ptr [rdx],rcx

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7E

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KxWaitForLockOwnerShip
01 nt!KeAcquireInStackQueuedSpinLockAtDpcLevel
02 nt!MiUnlinkPageFromLockedList
03 nt!MiGatherMappedPages
04 nt!MiMappedPageWriter
05 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup
06 nt!KiStartSystemThread


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  28c09789f81362db835bfb028a5ab3b8588a4574

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  fed4c94be63eb750e0aed24dce2a0e902274ed07

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  30a3e915496deaace47137d5b90c3ecc03746bf6

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.1.7601.19018

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7E_nt!KxWaitForLockOwnerShip+12

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7E_nt!KxWaitForLockOwnerShip+12

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  X64_0x7E_nt!KxWaitForLockOwnerShip+12

OSBUILD:  7601

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 7

OSEDITION:  Windows 7 WinNt (Service Pack 1) TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2015-09-29 03:55:44

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  150928-1507

BUILDLAB_STR:  win7sp1_gdr

BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.1.7601.19018.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.150928-1507

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x7e_nt!kxwaitforlockownership+12
```

The `nt!Mi` calls are Memory Management functions.

So you may have RAM issue. Your use Corsair Vengeance (`CMY8GX3M2A2400C11`) RAM which often causes stability issues when using an ASUS motherboard (`M5A99X EVO R2.0`).

So first test your RAM with memtest86+, if the RAM is fine, go to the BIOS/UEFI and use slower RAM timings. If nothing helps, try other RAM (but this time not from Corsair).

Comment: I have run memtest86+ with it saying there are no problems and I have not had this issus untill recently it was working fin befor the ram was the same ram I put in when I build the system the only new part is the harddrive

Comment: change the RAM timings in the BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Ok so I've removed the Corsair Vengeance RAM and its make no change expet what you would expet from lossing half your RAM, as for changing the timing, what would you sagest

Comment: I'm started to get to the end of my tether with this,

However I had a thought If windows 10 did mess us something in my setting then maybe...Just maybe...If I restore the BIOS to the factory defaults and then maybe that might fix what ever is going wrong.

well its the last think I can think of before thought the entire thing out my window and swearing of technology as when even its had a crash I can't work (stream) on it until hours later.

Comment: post some pictures of CPU-Z (memory and SPD tab for all RAM modules).

Comment: with http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html?

Comment: yes post pictures of this tool

Comment: http://industrialdimensions.co.uk/CPU-Z/CPU-Z/

Comment: Ok there are screen shots of each tap just encase there is somthing there that might help
P.S. I know my website is in major need of updating and redesigning

Comment: you mix Samsumg and Corsair RAM and run the Samsung at 861MHz where it only supports 666Mhz. So go to the BIOS/UEFI and change the memory speed to 666/1333Mhz with timings of 9-9-9-24-33

Comment: Ok so I could not find a easy way to do that with in the BIOS so instead I have just removed that RAM and put back in the corsair RAM.
so far so good, I've not had a crash yet but I am still holding my breath

Comment: use your smartphone and take some pictures of your BIOS/UEFI and post them

Comment: http://industrialdimensions.co.uk/CPU-Z/BIOS/
there every shot I could think of, sorry for qulity, my phone sucks
also it crashed again, however i have noticed a patton, if it freze crashes when I next try to play a game after rebooting it will BSOD

Comment: disable this AI overclcok and in the RAM option, where everything is auto, select manual and try to select 9-9-9-24-33

Comment: Ok I will give that a go and see what happens

Comment: Ok, I have no Idea what I'm doing in this bios, help?

Comment: have you disabled all OC settings and tried to manually select the setting? I don't know your BIOS/UEFI so I can't really help

Comment: I think so, how ever I have a clue what setting to change...there are a lot of them

Comment: so im unsure what RAM setting to tuch as the last thing I want is to damage anything